# using Jquery to autolimit text field input to numbers only?

Tags: jquery, validation

been doing some research, but haven't found a solution for me.  Basically, I have a small admin section that requires number inputs for calculations. ONLY numbers.  BUT, the user can sometimes COPY AND PASTE including a $ or % character.

Now, I have found this: [input field, only numbers jquery/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276452/input-field-only-numbers-jquery-js)

```
$("input[type=text]").keypress(function (e){
  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

which works perfectly during TYPING, however, if the user copies and pastes "$1230", it keeps the $ in there. I would like it to auto-strip it....

SO, basically, I am thinking instead of "return false", I need some sort of "replace"?  Would that be the best way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `on` instead of `keypress`, with events for both `keypress` and `change`:

```
$("input[type=text]").on("keypress change", (function (e){
  var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I actually did try that! Well, I tried it with JUST change. :)   At any rate, this doesn't seem to work though. Even worse, I can now type anything into the text field and.... it randomly replace the whole thing sometimes.... haha

Comment: Forgive me, I had a syntax error with the closing parenthesis... It works perfectly except for when I copy and paste the characters in...